# Remove border from last navigation list item

Tags: html, css

I am trying to complete a navigation list that is contained within a div.

I have it set to have a border on the right of each item to space out each item. I am looking to have this border only on the middle items and not on the last item.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container-navigation">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_self">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html" target="_self">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html" target="_self">solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="training.html" target="_self">training</a></li>
        <li><a href="payments.html" target="_blank">payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" target="_self">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navigation li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Give the last item a unique class and create another CSS entry?

Comment: What browsers do you want to support?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by thgaskell, here is one way of doing it:

```css
#navigation li a {
    color: green;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
#navigation li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/G3mD9/

**Note:** the `last-child` pseudo-class is supported for IE9+, so a bit more limited than `first-child` which is good for IE7+.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would move the border to the left instead of the right:

```
#navigation li a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

And then I would use `first-child` as it is has good cross browser compatibility.

```
#navigation li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support older browsers (IE7+, etc...) you should flip the border from the right side to the left side, so that you can use the css selector `first-child`.

Change your current css from this:

```
#navigation li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

To:

```
#navigation li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#navigation li:first-child a {
    border-left: none;
}
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/zuPgC/)

Comment: Good point about IE7+ support, in contrast to `last-child` which is only good for IE9+ (up vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the :last-child Selector, the easy way.

```
#navigation li a:last-child {
     border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: It should be `#navigation li:last-child a`.

Comment: yes, you're right but it would not remove the border because its in the a tag.

Comment: It _is_ applied to the `a`. But you need to select the last `li`, not the last `a` of every `li` (which applies to every `a` since there's only one `a` in every `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Create new id or class name to last list item, then
give the style like that,

```
#id_name a { border-right:none !important; }
```

Comment: You don't need the `!important` option, the id by itself will increase the rule specificity enough to over ride the primary CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to :first-child, you can also use the adjacent sibling selector to get IE7+ support. It needs changing to border-left from border-right like other solutions too though.

```
#navigation li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px 6px 15px;
}
#navigation li + li a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```